# java threads synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In the class below, is the method `getIt()`  thread safe  and why?

```
public class X { 
  private long myVar; 
  public void setIt(long  var){ 
    myVar = var; 
   }  
   public long getIt() { 
     return myVar; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Or an interview question?

Comment: @finnw: Whenever you prefer :) What is the difference...? if you didn't contribute...? Do you want me to change the tags?

Comment: I was just curious because I have been asked a similar question at interview.  There is no need to change the tags.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is not thread-safe. Variables of type `long` and `double` in Java are treated as two separate 32-bit variables. One thread could be writing and have written half the value when another thread reads both halves. In this situation, the reader would see a value that was never supposed to exist.

To make this thread-safe you can either declare `myVar` as `volatile` (Java 1.5 or later) or make both `setIt` and `getIt` `synchronized`.

Note that even if `myVar` was a 32-bit `int` you could still run into threading issues where one thread could be reading an out of date value that another thread has changed. This could occur because the value has been cached by the CPU. To resolve this, you again need to declare `myVar` as `volatile` (Java 1.5 or later) or make both `setIt` and `getIt` `synchronized`.

It's also worth noting that if you are using the result of `getIt` in a subsequent `setIt` call, e.g. `x.setIt(x.getIt() * 2)`, then you probably want to `synchronize` across both calls:

```
synchronized(x)
{
  x.setIt(x.getIt() * 2);
}
```

Without the extra synchronization, another thread could change the value in between the `getIt` and `setIt` calls causing the other thread's value to be lost.

Comment: +1 This is a fact most developers are unaware. Instead of volatile, you could also use one of the Atomic* classes (found in java.util.concurrent) to better express you intent.

Answer (score 9):

This is not thread-safe. Even if your platform guarantees atomic writes of `long`, the lack of `synchronized` makes it possible that one thread calls `setIt()` and even after this call has finished it is possible that another thread can call `getIt()` and this call could return the old value of `myVar`.

The `synchronized` keyword does more than an exclusive access of one thread to a block or a method. It also guarantees that the second thread is informed about a change of a variable.

So you either have to mark both methods as `synchronized` or mark the member `myVar` as `volatile`.

There's a very good explanation about synchronization [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

> Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference. However, this does not eliminate all need to synchronize atomic actions, because memory consistency errors are still possible. Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads. What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not. At least, not on platforms that lack atomic 64-bit memory accesses.

Suppose that Thread A calls `setIt`, copies 32 bits into memory where the backing value is, and is then pre-empted before it can copy the other 32 bits.

Then Thread B calls `getIt`.

Comment: Even on platforms that provide atomic 64-bit memory access, you have to synchronize the get and set methods. Or you have to make the member volatile. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but too specific. There are much more general reasons as to why this is not synchronized - see @tangens answer.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not, because longs are not atomic in java, so one thread could have written 32 bits of the long in the setIt method, and then the getIt could read the value, and then setIt could set the other 32 bits.

So the end result is that getIt returns a value that was never valid.

Answer (score 2):

It ought to be, and generally is, but is not *guaranteed* to be thread safe.  There could be issues with different cores having different versions in CPU cache, or the store/retrieve not being atomic for all architectures.  Use the `AtomicLong` class.

Answer (score 0):

The getter is not thread safe because it’s not guarded by any mechanism that guarantees the most up-to-date visibility. Your choices are:

- making `myVar` final (but then you can’t mutate it)
- making `myVar` volatile
- use synchronized to accessing `myVar`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Modern JVMs no longer split long and double operations.  I don't know of any reference which states this is still a problem. For example, see AtomicLong which doesn't use synchronization in Sun's JVM.

Assuming you want to be sure it is not a problem then you can use synchronize both get() and set(). However, if you are performing an operation like add, i.e. set(get()+1) then this synchronization doesn't buy you much, you still have to synchronize the object for the whole operation.  (A better way around this is to use a single operation for add(n) which is synchronized)

However, a better solution is to use an AtomicLong.  This supports atomic operations like get, set and add and DOESN'T use synchronization.

Answer (score -4):

Since it is a read only method. You should synchronize the `set` method.

**EDIT** : I see why the get method needs to be synchronized as well. Good job explaining Phil Ross.

Comment: Both methods must be synchronized in order to make this definitely threadsafe. Otherwiese, the get method could yield a partially-changed version.